# How can I conditionally format any empty cell from column C to L if the respective cell in column B not empty

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting, microsoft-excel

I need your help with conditional formatting in Gsheet or Excel (I will choose one of them depending on the solution).

This format needs to be: Any empty cell in columns C to L must be highlighted if the respective cells in B are not empty.

It needs to look like this:
[image]

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to apply conditional formatting to the `C2:L` range with the custom formula:

```
=and($B2<>"",C2:L2="")
```

[image: cond]